# prove the following is true: $E\Big[~\Big|E[X_n|F_n]\Big|~\Big] \le \Bigg|E\Big[~E[X | F_n \Big]~ \Bigg|$

Tags: expected-value, martingales

$F_n$ is a filtration for IID random sequence $X_n$.

I want to prove that when you pull the absolute value to the outside of the Expectation, then it causes an inequality to be introduced. For example:

$E[X_n|F_n] = E[X_n|F_n]$

Take absolute value and expectation of both side.

$E\Big[~\Big|E[X_n|F_n]\Big|~\Big] = E\Big[~\Big|E[X_n|F_n]\Big|~\Big]$

on the RHS, Pull the absolute value to the outside of the expectation:

$E\Big[~\Big|E[X_n|F_n]\Big|~\Big] \le \Bigg|E\Big[~E[X | F_n \Big]~ \Bigg|$

Here an inequality is introduced.  Why is this true?

[image: martingale]

Comment: Don't you mean $\ge$ throughout?

Comment: for all random variable $X$, you have $|\mathbb E[X]|\leq \mathbb E[|X|]$ by Jensen inequality.

Comment: so you treat the absolute value as if its a function and apply jensen's inequality?

Comment: * **Jensen's Inequality**: if E[X] exists, and if f(x) is a **convex function**, then:

  $E[f(X)] \ge f(E[X])$

Comment: What you put in red is wrong. If $X$ is not $L^1$ or if $X$ is not positive a.s., then $X_n\notin L^1$ (yes to answer to your previous question).

Comment: Put @+Name if you want that the person see your comment. @pico

Comment: I think it doesn't introduce an inequality to pull an absolute value out of an expectation... its equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand your previous comment, but if you think that $\mathbb E[|X|]\leq |\mathbb E[X]|$, then it's wrong if $X$ is not positive a.s.

Comment: So where does this excerpt appear?  Maybe from a book with many typos, or maybe from a book that withholds important hypotheses?

Comment: Schaum's outline Probability, Random Variables, and Random Processes...